# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, .net-assembly

I got Unknown build error quoted below:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Unknown build error, 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'Amisys.Data, Version=5.1.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044) Line 8 Position
>   32.'

I built 'Amisys.Data' (I checked on Sign the assembly) with Signing when I built first and and built again after deletion of strong named key and unchecking Sign the assembly unchecked, means cleared all strong named assembly.

When I compile the executable assembly which unchecked reference added, I got error like above.

Is there any way to clear that out and make it work?

Regards
Joon

Comment: The project file still remembers it being signed.  Remove the reference and add it back.

Comment: I did as you said but it doesn't work.